# How to Bind a nullable bool in VM to RadRadioButton

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, nullable

I am struggling with how I go about this?  In my VM I have a `nullable bool` property that I want to bind to a Yes/No(*true/false*) `RadRadioButton`.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

VM

```
public bool? IsSDS { get; set; }
```

View

```
<telerik:Label Content="Self Directed Support" />
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportYes" Content="Yes" />
     <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportNo" Content="No" />
</StackPanel>
```

---

EDIT

I thought this was working but I was mistaken.  Only Yes is binding.  Below is what's on my View, `CreateAuthView`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
   <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="Authorization_SelfDirectedSupportYes" GroupName="SDS" Content="Yes" />
    <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="Authorization_SelfDirectedSupportNo" GroupName="SDS" Content="No" />
</StackPanel>
```

and here is the corresponding portion on my ViewModel, `CreateAuthViewModel`:

```
public Authorization Authorization
{
    get
    {
       return this.authorization;
    }
    set
    {
       if (authorization != value)
       {
          this.authorization = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Authorization);                    
       }
    }
}
```

And finally the Property on my Model, `Authorization`:

```
public bool? SelfDirectedSupportYes
{
   get
   {
      return this.selfDirectedIndicator;
   }
   set
   {
      this.selfDirectedIndicator = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsChecked` is also of type `Nullable<bool>`, so you can bind it directly the "yes" radio button. And if you set the same `GroupName` for both radio buttons, you don't need to bind the "no" radio button at all (since checking "no" will uncheck "yes")

```
<telerik:Label Content="Self Directed Support" />
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportYes" GroupName="SelfDirectedSupportOption" Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding IsSDS}" />
     <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportNo" GroupName="SelfDirectedSupportOption" Content="No" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was hoping.  Now to see if Caliburn.Micro will still be able to do it's magic as long as I name one of the two radio buttons the same as the VM property....Thanks!

Comment: Less Awesome...The Yes is binding properly but not the No.  See my Edit please.

Comment: for reference, it does the same thing whether I allow CM to do the binding or I include `IsChecked="{Binding Authorization.SelfDirectedSupportYes}"`

Comment: And what do you mean when you say that the No is not binding? Only the Yes needs to be bound. If you check No, Yes becomes unchecked, which updates the binding source to False.

Comment: yup, if you notice my last comment it doesn't matter if I add the Binding like you showed or let Caliburn infer the Binding.  Same result.  Yes binds properly No does not.  So if I click Yes it sets the value to True.  If I click No it leaves it as Null just like if I didn't click anything.

Comment: Alright, I got it.  I wish I knew why Caliburn.Micro isn't doing what I thought it was supposed to but in the end I got it to work by adding this: `IsChecked="{Binding Authorization.IsSDS}"` Seems I was missing the Authorization portion.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportYes" IsChecked="{Binding IsSDS}" Content="Yes" />

    <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="SelfDirectedSupportNo" IsChecked="{Binding IsSDS, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" Content="No" />






    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
       public class InverseBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
    {
       #region IValueConverter Members

         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
         if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

          return !(bool)value;
       }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
       }

        #endregion
     }
```

Comment: Use a ValueConverter that inverts a bool property. Then make this a StaticResource in you usercontrol or window.

Comment: @Jeff, you don't need the converter at all (see my answer)

Comment: Nice work.... Obviously I'm decided to over complicate. I was probably thinking of checkboxes in my mind!